# SQL server return only single row or null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query which I only ever want to return 1 row. If there are multiple rows, I want to return null.

I guess I can do it with something like

```
SELECT whatever FROM MyTable
 WHERE something = myQuery
   AND ( COUNT(SELECT whatever FROM MyTable
             WHERE something = myQuery) = 1)
```

but that's pretty nasty and I wondered if there as a neater way of doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cant you do:

```
SELECT whatever FROM
    (
       SELECT whatever, COUNT(*) As NumRecords
       FROM MyTable
       WHERE something = myQuery
       GROUP BY whatever
       HAVING NumRecords = 1
    )
```

Comment: very nice. KISS is always better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`IF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) clause to check for a single row and only select if that's the case:

```
IF SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE something = myQuery) = 1
  BEGIN
    SELECT whatever FROM MyTable
     WHERE something = myQuery
  END
```

Comment: i'm confused - that's just his original query with an IF at the start? EDIT: just saw your edit, :)

Comment: still needs two queries though - not required (IMO)

Comment: @RPM1984 - Your version is indeed a single query, however, if there are multiple columns to be returned...

Comment: Yes, true - but you could get around that by changing the `select whatever from (` to an inner join on the subquery, the grouping remains on the one field - but the outer query will select all the columns. see your point though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, another way may be:

```
select f1, f2, f3
  from your_table
 where f4 = f5*2
 group by f1, f2, f3
having count(1) = 1
```

Don't know if it's neater than your solution though.

Answer (score 0):

set rowcount 1

Before the select statement.

Later,

set rowcount 0

Answer (score 0):

We can add it this way too,

```
SELECT max(whatever) as whatever
FROM MyTable
WHERE something = myQuery
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 1
```